# Какой Property отвечает за наведение на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx

хочу чтобы когда на `Button` `JavaFX` наводился курсор, он подсвечивалась. Как это сделать? Не нашел подходящего `Property`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы хотите просто стиль поменять при наведения курсора то Вы можете достичь этого с помощю css, просто задав нужный вам параметр в псевдоклассе `:hover`.

```
.your-class:hover {
// some parameters
}
```

то есть Вам надо будет записать стили в css файл и подключить его как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22048338/8973424). Потом добавить класс стиля или идентификацию в `Button`.

style.css файл

```
.my-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Вот и java класс.

```
package styled.button;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StyledButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.getStylesheets()
                .add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());

        Button button = new Button("Hover Button");
        button.getStyleClass().add("my-button");

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, 400, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

При наведения курсора задний фон кнопки изменится на зеленый.

или же это можно сделать программно:

```
package button.hover;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonHover extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

        Button button = new Button("Hover Button");
        button.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        });
        button.setOnMouseExited(event -> button.setStyle(""));

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, 400, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 вариант хороший, как задать для конкретной кнопки?

Answer (score 0):

[onMouseEntered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseEnteredProperty):

Определяет функцию, которая будет вызываться, когда мышь над элементом.